# CreateWindowEx заголовок окна содержит только одну букву

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, windows-10, pinvoke

Не понимаю причину возникновения данной проблемы, однако, заголовок окна, всегда будет иметь одну букву, по непонятным мне причинам.

Класс окна, имеет переданную в структуру  `WndClassEx` строку, однако окно, ни коим образом не хочет полностью скопировать переданную строку, для установки заголовка окна. В тоже время, вызов `SetWindowText`, делает тоже самое, а точнее устанавливает только одну букву из строки в заголовок окна.

Не уверен что представленный мной код сможет воспроизвести мою проблему, но я на это надеюсь:

```
public class RenderWindow
{
    #region Fields

    private IntPtr _windowHandle;
    private readonly NativeMethods.WndProc _windowProc;
    private IntPtr _applicationInstance;
    private string _windowTitle;
    private string _windowClass;

    #endregion

    #region Props

    public Rect ClientRect
    {
        get
        {
            Rect rect = new Rect();
            NativeMethods.GetClientRect(_windowHandle, ref rect);
            return rect;
        }
    }

    public Rect Rect
    {
        get
        {
            Rect rect = new Rect();
            NativeMethods.GetWindowRect(_windowHandle, ref rect);
            return rect;
        }
    }

    public bool IsValid
    {
        get { return NativeMethods.IsWindow(_windowHandle); }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    private void RegisterWindowClass(ref NativeMethods.WndClassEx wndClass)
    {
        wndClass.style = NativeMethods.ClassStyle.VerticalRedraw |
                         NativeMethods.ClassStyle.HorizontalRedraw |
                         NativeMethods.ClassStyle.OwnDrawingContext;

        wndClass.hInstance = _applicationInstance;

        ushort classAtom = NativeMethods.RegisterClassEx(ref wndClass);
        int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

        if (0 != classAtom)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (errorCode == NativeMethods.ERR.CLASS_ALREADY_EXIST)
        {
            return;
        }

        throw new Win32Exception(errorCode);
    }

    public bool Initialize(IntPtr instance, int width, int height,
        string windowTitle = "DirectX.NET Window",
        string windowClass = "DirectX_NET_WindowClass")
    {
        _applicationInstance = instance;
        _windowClass = windowClass;
        _windowTitle = windowTitle;

        NativeMethods.WndClassEx wndClass = new NativeMethods.WndClassEx(0, _windowProc, _windowClass, instance);

        RegisterWindowClass(ref wndClass);
        const NativeMethods.WindowStyles styles =
            NativeMethods.WindowStyles.WS_CAPTION | NativeMethods.WindowStyles.WS_MINIMIZEBOX |
            NativeMethods.WindowStyles.WS_OVERLAPPED | NativeMethods.WindowStyles.WS_SYSMENU;

        Rect windowRect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
        NativeMethods.AdjustWindowRect(ref windowRect, styles, false);

        _windowHandle = NativeMethods.CreateWindow
        (
            _windowClass,
            _windowTitle,
            styles,
            unchecked((int) 0x80000000),
            unchecked((int) 0x80000000),
            windowRect.Right - windowRect.Left,
            windowRect.Bottom - windowRect.Top,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            IntPtr.Zero
        );

        int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

        if (IntPtr.Zero == _windowHandle)
        {
            Win32Exception ex = new Win32Exception(errorCode);
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            return false;
        }

        Show();
        NativeMethods.SetForegroundWindow(_windowHandle);
        NativeMethods.SetFocus(_windowHandle);

        return true;
    }

    public void Show()
    {
        NativeMethods.ShowWindow(_windowHandle, NativeMethods.SW.SHOW);
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        NativeMethods.CloseWindow(_windowHandle);
    }

    public bool ProcessMessages()
    {
        Msg msg = new Msg();

        if (NativeMethods.PeekMessage(ref msg, _windowHandle, 0U, 0U, NativeMethods.PM.REMOVE))
        {
            NativeMethods.TranslateMessage(ref msg);
            NativeMethods.DispatchMessage(ref msg);
        }

        if (NativeMethods.WM.NULL != msg.Message)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (IsValid)
        {
            return true;
        }

        _windowHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        NativeMethods.UnregisterClass(_windowClass, _applicationInstance);
        return false;
    }

    public RenderWindow()
    {
        _windowProc = OnMessage;
    }

    internal virtual IntPtr OnMessage(IntPtr hwnd, NativeMethods.WM msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        switch (msg)
        {
            default:
                return NativeMethods.DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }

    // Класс будет абстрактным, я удалил все абстрактные методы.

    #endregion
}
```

```
internal class NativeMethods
{
    #region Constants

    private const string User32 = "user32.dll";

    #endregion

    #region Deleagtes

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    internal delegate IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, WM msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    #endregion

    #region Errors

    public static class ERR
    {
        public const int
            CLASS_ALREADY_EXIST = 1410,
            CLASS_DOES_NOT_EXIST = 1411,
            CLASS_HAS_WINDOWS = 1412;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Structs

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal ref struct WndClassEx
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] public int cbSize;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] public ClassStyle style;
        public IntPtr lpfnWndProc; // not WndProc
        public int cbClsExtra;
        public int cbWndExtra;
        public IntPtr hInstance;
        public IntPtr hIcon;
        public IntPtr hCursor;
        public IntPtr hbrBackground;
        public string lpszMenuName;
        public string lpszClassName;
        public IntPtr hIconSm;

        public WndClassEx
        (
            ClassStyle style,
            WndProc wndProc,
            string className,
            IntPtr instance,
            int clsExtra = 0, int wndExtra = 0)
        {
            cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WndClassEx));
            this.style = style;
            lpfnWndProc = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(wndProc);
            cbClsExtra = clsExtra;
            cbWndExtra = wndExtra;
            hInstance = instance == IntPtr.Zero ? Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.BaseAddress : instance;
            hIcon = IntPtr.Zero;
            hCursor = IntPtr.Zero;
            hbrBackground = IntPtr.Zero;
            lpszMenuName = null;
            lpszClassName = className;
            hIconSm = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal ref struct MinMaxInfo
    {
        private readonly Point _ptReserved;
        internal Point MaxSize;
        internal Point MaxPosition;
        internal Point MinTrackSize;
        internal Point MaxTrackSize;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Enums
    [Flags]
    public enum WindowStylesEx : uint
    {
        // Все что не используется в примере, было удалено
    }
    internal enum WM : uint
    {
        NULL = 0x0000,
        // Все что не используется в примере, было удалено
    }
    [Flags]
    internal enum WindowStyles : uint
    {
        WS_CAPTION = 0xc00000,
        WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x20000,
        WS_OVERLAPPED = 0x0,
        WS_SYSMENU = 0x80000,
        // Все что не используется в примере, было удалено
    }
    internal static class SW
    {
        internal const int
            SHOW = 5;

        // Все что не используется в примере, было удалено
    }

    internal static class PM
    {
        internal const uint
            REMOVE = 0x0001U;
        // Все что не используется в примере, было удалено
    }
    [Flags]
    internal enum ClassStyle : uint
    {
        VerticalRedraw = 0x0001U,
        HorizontalRedraw = 0x0002U,
        OwnDrawingContext = 0x0020U
        // Все что не используется в примере, было удалено
    }

    #endregion

    #region DllImport

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateWindowEx
    (
        WindowStylesEx dwExStyle,
        string lpClassName,
        string lpWindowName,
        WindowStyles dwStyle,
        int x,
        int y,
        int nWidth,
        int nHeight,
        IntPtr hWndParent,
        IntPtr hMenu,
        IntPtr hInstance,
        IntPtr lpParam
    );

    internal static IntPtr CreateWindow
    (
        string windowClass,
        string windowTitle,
        WindowStyles styles,
        int x,
        int y,
        int width,
        int height,
        IntPtr parentWindowHandle,
        IntPtr menuHandle,
        IntPtr hInstance,
        IntPtr lParam
    )
    {
        return CreateWindowEx
        (
            0U,
            windowClass,
            windowTitle,
            styles,
            x,
            y,
            width,
            height,
            parentWindowHandle,
            menuHandle,
            hInstance,
            lParam
        );
    }

    [DllImport(User32, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool IsWindow(IntPtr windowHandle);

    [DllImport(User32, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool CloseWindow(IntPtr windowHandle);

    [DllImport(User32, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr windowHandle, int show);

    [DllImport(User32, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr windowHandle, ref Rect rect);

    [DllImport(User32, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool GetClientRect(IntPtr windowHandle, ref Rect rect);

    [DllImport(User32, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern ushort RegisterClassEx([In] ref WndClassEx wndClassEx);

    [DllImport(User32, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool AdjustWindowRect
    (
        ref Rect rectangle,
        WindowStyles styles,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool hasMenu
    );

    [DllImport(User32,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
        SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern IntPtr DefWindowProc(IntPtr hwnd, WM msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport(User32,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
        SetLastError = true,
        CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool PeekMessage
    (
        ref Msg msg,
        IntPtr hwnd,
        uint filterMin,
        uint filterMax,
        uint pmReason
    );

    [DllImport(User32,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
        SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool TranslateMessage(ref Msg msg);

    [DllImport(User32,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
        SetLastError = true,
        CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool DispatchMessage(ref Msg msg);

    [DllImport(User32,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
        SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr windowHandle);

    [DllImport(User32,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
        SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool SetFocus(IntPtr windowHandle);

    [DllImport(User32,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
        SetLastError = true,
        CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool UnregisterClass(string className, IntPtr handle);

    [DllImport(User32,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
        SetLastError = true,
        CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool SetWindowText(IntPtr windowHandle, StringBuilder title);

    #endregion
}

/// <summary>
///     Contains message information from a thread's message queue.
/// </summary>
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential),
 DebuggerDisplay("[WindowHandle:X8, Message, WParam, LParam, Time, Point]")]
internal readonly ref struct Msg
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     A handle to the window whose window procedure receives the message.
    ///     This member is <see cref="IntPtr.Zero" /> when the message is a thread message.
    /// </summary>
    public readonly IntPtr WindowHandle;

    /// <summary>
    ///     The message identifier.
    ///     Applications can only use the low word; the high word is reserved by the system.
    /// </summary>
    public readonly NativeMethods.WM Message;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Additional information about the <see cref="Message" />.
    ///     The exact meaning depends on the value of the message member.
    /// </summary>
    public readonly IntPtr WParam;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Additional information about the <see cref="Message" />.
    ///     The exact meaning depends on the value of the message member.
    /// </summary>
    public readonly IntPtr LParam;

    /// <summary>
    ///     The time at which the message was posted.
    /// </summary>
    public readonly uint Time;

    /// <summary>
    ///     The cursor position, in screen coordinates, when the message was posted.
    /// </summary>
    public readonly Point Point;

    private readonly uint _reserved;
}

/// <summary>
///     The <see cref="Point" /> structure defines the X- and Y- coordinates of a point.
/// </summary>
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential),
 DebuggerDisplay("[X: {X}, Y: {Y}]")]
public ref struct Point
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     The X-coordinate of the point.
    /// </summary>
    public int X;

    /// <summary>
    ///     The Y-coordinate of the point.
    /// </summary>
    public int Y;

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential),
 DebuggerDisplay("X:{Left}, Y:{Top}, [{Right-Left}x{Bottom-Top}]")]
public ref struct Rect
{
    public readonly int Left;
    public readonly int Top;
    public readonly int Right;
    public readonly int Bottom;

    public Rect(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
    {
        Left = left;
        Top = top;
        Right = right;
        Bottom = bottom;
    }
}
```

Как это можно исправить, и какие могут быть причины такого поведения?

Код для запуска окна:

```
public static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    public static int Main()
    {
        RenderWindow window = new RenderWindow();
        window.Initialize(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.BaseAddress, 1280, 720);

        while (window.ProcessMessages())
        {
            Rect clientRect = window.ClientRect;
        }


        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: По симптомам - вызов ANSI функции и передача ей юникодной строки

Comment: Я уже пытался явно указывать функцию импорта через `EntryPoint = "CreateWindowExW"`, эффект к сожалению тот же. А еще вызов `IsWindowUnicode`, возвращает `true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот ваша проблема

> ```
> [DllImport(User32,
>     CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
>     SetLastError = true)]
> internal static extern IntPtr DefWindowProc(IntPtr hwnd, WM msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
> ```

Вы импортируете ансишную функцию и передаете ей юникодную строку для обработки.

Импорт должен быть такой

```
[DllImport(User32,
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
    SetLastError = true,
    CharSet = CharSet.Unicode
)]
internal static extern IntPtr DefWindowProc(IntPtr hwnd, WM msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

Comment: Точно! Как же я не заметил :)